# Creating vertex array in loop - OpenGL

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Just started working with OpenGL ES 2.0 and was wondering about the best way to construct vertex arrays. Right now, I have a struct where I keep adding new vertices in it for like... 5000 times(increments of 1).

For me, this seems to be quite a slow way to generate a vertex array.

Maybe all the values should just be saved once when they are created? Then just have them in the beginning of the file like...

Vertex Vertices[...] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}}
    ...
};

Is that better? or do we have other choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vertices are constants and the quantity is big, I recommend save it in a binary file and load in server side memory [(using glBufferData)](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) when you start your application.

If you are asking about data order, it is recommended save your data in a order that it will be read by [vertexAttribPoint](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml). For example, if you have 3 vertex coordinate (X,Y,Z) and 4 vertex color (R,G,B,A), the GPU will read your data faster if you create it in this order inside glBuffer: { X1, Y1, Z1, R1, G1, B1, A1, X2, Y2, Z2, R2, G2, B2, A2, ....}.

Normally, the problem is not the time wasted for create/load the vertex data in your application, but the time wasted to renderer theses data.

But everything depends of the propose of your application.